# Reactive Depth-First Search with cut

Tags: c#, closures, system.reactive, depth-first-search, side-effects

I am trying to develop a reactive DFS implementation that produces distinct nodes, without traversing unnecessary paths. The tree may contain duplicate/equal nodes. If a node has been traversed, then all of it's children have been traversed as well, hence we can stop expanding the traversal if we re-encounter a node.

```
class Traversal {
  //exposed method with understandable signature
  public IObservable<Node> DepthFirst(Node root) {
    return DepthFirstRecursive(root, new List<Node>(), new SomeStatefulHelper());
  }

  //hidden method with accumulator for cutting
  private IObservable<Node> DepthFirstRecursive(Node root, List<Node> accuFilter, SomeHelper helper) {
    return root.GetChildren().AsObservable()

      //here we cut traversal:
      .Where(n => !accuFilter.Contains(n))

      //cannot do SelectMany, because we want sequential processing:
      .Select(n => DepthFirstRecursive(n, accuFilter, helper)).Concat()
      .Concat(Observable.Return(root))

      //adding results to accumulator
      .Do(accuFilter.Add)
  }
}

class Node : IEquatable<Node> {
  public IEnumerable<Node> GetChildren(SomeHelper helper) {
    //produce child nodes
  }
  ...
}
```

The accumulator is not pretty. It's basically a side effect woven through the otherwise elegant reactive implementation. **How can I get rid of it using Rx?** `Observable.Distinct()` is not going to cut it (pun intended), since that can only operate at the very end of the chain (where the `.Do` is).

Also, with the helper I'm getting an "Implicitly captured closure: helper" warning on the `=>` in the `.Where`. I don't see that this warning is relevant. Is it? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: _The tree may contain duplicate/equal nodes_ => It's not a tree then, but a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)

Comment: I meant that there may be nodes that are equal (`a.Equals(b)` returns true). They are *different* instances.

Comment: @3D-Grabber, ooh "DAG", that's a new one - thank you. In one of my previous lives, this type of thing was always known as an" N-squared", ie a matrix of dimensions N x N in which each cell defines the relationship (or lack of relationship) between the two corresponding elements. An N-squared matrix has the advantage over a diagram where different types relationship need to be represented; in diagram form, you would need to encode or label the arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think RX is the right tool for the job here.

Also, you should use a HashSet to keep track of the visited nodes. 
List.Contains() iterates over all elements, so you will introduce O(n^2) behavior.

To flatten the result it's easiest to use Enumerable.SelectMany()

Instead of relying on a extra class to implement GetChildren() you can simply use a delegate `Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren` that specifies how to get the children of the node type in question.

This is how I would do it:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirst<T>(T node, 
                                               Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren, 
                                               HashSet<T> visitedNodes)
    {
        return getChildren(node)
              .Where(visitedNodes.Add)
              .SelectMany(child => DepthFirst(child, getChildren, visitedNodes))
              .Concat(new[] { node });
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirst<T>(T root, 
                                               Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren) 
    {
        return DepthFirst(root, getChildren, new HashSet<T> {root});
    }
```